# Accidentally included a breakpoint - how do I undo my mistake? (thread 1: breakpoint 1.1)

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

Whenever I try to run my code for my sign up view controller, I am brought back to my code in which they are displaying there is a breakpoint. I've pressed command + 7, the blue line was on the 34th line:

ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        userStorage = storage.child("users")}

^ Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Understanding and using breakpoints is such a critical part of modern development that you should use this as a "teaching moment" and learn to use breakpoints, examine variables, continue, etc. @marfarja told you one way to get rid of your unintended breakpoint, but if you don't learn how to use breakpoints you'll slow your learning down a great deal.

Comment: [Debugging with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/about_debugging_w_xcode.html) -> Debugging Tools -> Breakpoints and the Breakpoint Navigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode find the blue chevron-icon for the relevant break-point you want to delete in the code. Hovering over the blue icon with your mouse simply control-click and then select 'delete breakpoint'.

Comment: Or click and drag it outside of the bar which shows breakpoints/line numbers.